# Laravel Blade handover variables for HTML tags

Tags: php, html, laravel

I've got a modal in an blade file and want to set the id tag from another blade file.

My modal blade:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal{{title}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal{{title}}Title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            @yield('modal-content')
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How do I set those arguments correctly?
I have tried:
@section('title', 'Test')

But it translates to the following and give an 500:
`id="modal{<?php echo title; ?>}"`

Comment: Try `id="modal@{{title}}"`

Comment: This will result in: 
```id="modal{{title}}"```

Comment: I think dollar symbol missing.... 
`id="modal{{$title}}"`

Comment: `title` is the js variable or php? If php, then it would be `{{ $title }}`

Comment: @STA No, I want to set it with @section('title', 'Test') in the blade file which extends the base modal blade.

Comment: You want to set the title in a @section in a seperate blade file?

Comment: @GreenPepper yes. I've got multiple modals and want to have on master modal blade.

Comment: @mago But the only thing changing through the modals should be the title?

Comment: @GreenPepper No, I need to give the modals a unique Id in order to call them

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround to get it working:

```
@section('title')
  {{ $title = 'test' }}
@endsection
```

using template text: `id="modal{{$title}}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
@section('modalTitle', 'YOUR_TITLE')

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal{{ @yield('title') }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal{{title}}Title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            @yield('modal-content')
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```